# Make flex-wrap ignore certain elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a 4-column flex-box layout with flex-wrap enabled:

[image]

When I resize the page and the edge of page touches the `<h1>` header, the blue column correctly wraps down:

[image]

What I now want to do is to add let's say 25 images next to each other inside a div that overflows on x, brings up a scrollbar, but doesn't wrap the blue column downwards unless the other content gets too small

[image]

So the scrollbar comes up correctly, but as soon as it does, the blue column tries to expand and wraps down. I want the image reel to always be smaller than the blue column, but even if i set it to 50% width, it still expands the blue column which then wraps.

Is there a way to only make the blue column wrap if the content is smaller than the `<h1>` tag and totally ignore the image reel?

I've made a [codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/JanVladimirMostert/pen/ExjROep) for it and also added sample code below:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.black {
  background-color: black;
}

.display\:flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-direction\:column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-direction\:row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrap\:wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-grow\:100 {
  flex-grow: 100;
}

.flex-grow\:2 {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.flex-grow\:1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex-grow\:0 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.flex-shrink\:1 {
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.height\:100vh {
  height: 100vh;
}

.reel {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.reel>img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.reel>*+* {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="display:flex flex-direction:row flex-wrap:wrap height:100vh">
  <div class="black flex-grow:0">
    Column1
  </div>
  <div class="red flex-grow:1">
    Column2
    <br />
    <input>
    <br />
    <input>

  </div>
  <div class="green flex-grow:2">
    Column3
    <br />
    <input>
    <br />
    <input>
  </div>
  <div class="blue flex-grow:100">
    <h1>
      This is some long header text in Column4
    </h1>
    <div class="reel">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have seen this before, but why use `.class\:value` in your CSS rules? Added value? In the mean time looking into your problem...

Comment: Don't allow your images to shrink `.reel>img { flex-shrink: 0 }`, that'll show the scrollbar. Not sure when the blue box should wrap.

Comment: What grow factors do you want the columns to have? In the first mock-up, it looks like they should all shrink to their minimum width with the fourth column filling the rest of the space. So, do the columns need to have `flex-grow` 0, 1, 2, and 100? `flex-grow:100` looks particularly unusual.

Comment: i want the first 3 columns to be at their minimum width at all times unless the last column runs out of space (excluding the image reel which should never impact the width of the blue column) in which case the second and third columns should fill the space and the last column should wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Settings `.reel>img { flex-shrink: 0 }` will show the scrollbar under your images

2) When you don't use `flex-grow` for relative growth compared to sibling elements, but just set `.red,.green,.blue { flex-grow: 1 }` and use `flex-basis: xx%` per color then the wrapping occurs.

Somehow the browser needs a width to work with. See `/* ADDED CODE */` in the CSS...

**UPDATE**

The OP inquired:

> Is there a way to keep the black, red and green columns from taking up more space than they need so that the blue column eats up all the available space?

This can be achieved by setting all but `.blue` to `flex-grow: 0; flex-basis: auto` (flexbox defaults) to start with and `.blue flexbasis` to a percentage > 0% and < 100% (more exact: less than 100% minus the total width of `.black`, `.red` and `.green`). Setting `.blue { flex-basis: auto }` will not work as it will immediately wrap because of its `flex-grow: 1`.

Updated the code to reflect the above (OVERRIDE 1) and added the final values the OP eventually used (OVERRIDE 2).

Simply try and see what works for you...

```css
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: white;
        }

/* ADDED CODE (original answer) */
.black  { flex-basis:  5% } /* example values */
.red    { flex-basis: 15% }
.green  { flex-basis: 30% }
.blue   { flex-basis: 50% } /* [MUST] add up to 100% */

        .reel > img {
            flex-shrink: 0;
        }

/* OVERRIDE 1: ADDED CODE, as per OP remarks (UPDATE) */
.black  { flex-basis: auto }
.red    { flex-basis: auto }
.green  { flex-basis: auto }
.blue   { flex-basis: 25%  }

/* OVERRIDE 2: OP final choice */
.black  { flex-basis:  50px }
.red    { flex-basis: 100px }
.green  { flex-basis: 100px }
.blue   { flex-basis:  25%  }

/**/
        .green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .black {
            background-color: black;
        }

        .display\:flex {
            display: flex;
        }

        .flex-direction\:column {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .flex-direction\:row {
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .flex-wrap\:wrap {
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .flex-grow\:100 {
            flex-grow: 100;
        }

        .flex-grow\:2 {
            flex-grow: 2;
        }

        .flex-grow\:1 {
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .flex-grow\:0 {
            flex-grow: 0;
        }

        .flex-shrink\:1 {
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }

        .height\:100vh {
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .reel {
            display: flex;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }


        .reel > img {
            height: auto;
            max-width: 25%;
        }

        .reel > * + * {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<body class="width:100%">
<div class="display:flex flex-direction:row flex-wrap:wrap height:100vh">
    <div class="black flex-grow:0">
        Column1
    </div>
    <div class="red flex-grow:1">
        Column2
        <br />
        <input>
        <br />
        <input>

    </div>
    <div class="green flex-grow:1">
        Column3
        <br />
        <input>
        <br />
        <input>
    </div>
    <div class="blue flex-grow:1">
        <h1>
            This is some long header text in Column4
        </h1>
        <div class="reel">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/M7LUTq5.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: this is a good solution! Is there a way to keep the black, red and green columns from taking up more space than they need so that the blue column eats up all the available space? I'll go read up on flex-basis in the meantime and see what my options are.

Comment: Probably set all but `.blue`  to `flex-grow: 0; flex-basis: auto` (flexbox defaults) to start with and `.blue flexbasis` to a percentage you can work with (the higher the %, the sooner it wraps), but when `.blue` wraps the other colors won't grow to fill the gap (unless that is what you want, of course).

Comment: FYI, saw that the % on `.blue flex-basis` doesn't matter, as long it is not 0% or lower than 100% minus (computed?) widths of the others (to keep things simple). `.blue flex-basis: auto` will make it wrap immediately because of the `flex-grow: 1`

Comment: i gave it an upvote, this is very close to what i'm looking for, just need to experiment with your solution a bit and get it working 100%, then i'll accept it

i need the other colours to fill the remainder of the space when the blue wraps, but only when it wraps, otherwise blue needs to fill as much of the space as possible. 

will play around with percentages and see if i can get it just right

Comment: flex-basis: 50px then 100px then 100px and then 25% on the blue column does exactly what i need, the other columns stay relatively fixed and the blue column only wraps once it gets smaller than 25% of its original size.